# Selecting the text of a selected option of a Select

Tags: react-select

After looking at react-select code, experimenting a bit, and checking several examples, like: https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/
It appears to me that once you select an option from the drop down, you can edit from scratch it by entering a new value, but you cannot select the current value the mouse (for example, to copy paste it, or to slightly modify it instead of writing from scratch).
Is these a way (e.g. a property) that I can use so that once I give focus to the Select element current value, the value itself becomes editable in the input element?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly same happened to me

Comment: hah! So, basically, no one cares enough about selecting text in a React Select element?

Comment: have you managed to get this to work? i need mine to be editable as well